# Requests time out, voting results in errors, sporadically can't accept answers

Tags: support, stack-overflow, 408-timeout

I use SO from my work PC all the time.  I know we have a quirky firewall/AV, but I consistently have trouble with SO.

Oftentimes, when I click on links on the page, the request times out.  I've just gotten used to clicking on links multiple times to get the pages to load.

Voting is another beast entirely.  Oftentimes, when I vote on several answers in a discussion and then click on to another page, I get an error message and my votes don't count.  I may have to try several times to cast my votes; it gets quite annoying.

Accepting answers also causes trouble.  Oftentimes, nothing happens when I click on the checkmark.  I must refresh the page and click the checkmark over and over to accept the answer.

Ordinarily, I would think that my internet connection is just not very good, but I have these specific problems only on SO.  Only on SO have I gotten used to clicking links several times before they open.  Only on SO am I used to having to input data more than once.

What could it be about SO that I have this problem?

Comment: This happens to me too, several times a day, and I have never seen it occur on any other website.  I'm running Chrome, on Fedora 13.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I know we have a quirky firewall/AV,

... is most likely the problem. You probably also have a proxy which [may or may not] be mangling your requests, caching forever despite being advised otherwise or (in some cases) blocking or (gasp) caching the CDN that delivers necessary elements to make the site work (again, disregarding advice from responses).

Comment: but then again, this behavior happens only on SO

Comment: @Rising Star: presumably you have tested every other site on the interwebs to make that assertion? :)  (In other words, "what is your sample set of sites?")

Comment: My sample of sites is everything I've visited from my work computer.  The SO sites are the *only* place I've seen this happen.  Not only that, but it happens on a regular basis.